# AspNetCore.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel. is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, rdlc

To the best of my knowledge, Microsoft currently does not have any plans to release an official Reporting Services/ReportViewer package for .NET Core. That's why, I am utilizing the third-party RDLC reporting library **[AspNetCore.ReportingServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting)** within a .NET Core 5 Project as a Reporting Service. 
 
Within the RDLC Report, certain columns require the ability to be shown or hidden. Here is an example of a Column Visibility Expression formula:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!leave_encashment.Value) = 0, True, False);
```

However, upon downloading the Excel report, I encountered the following error.

> An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native
> compiler return value: ‘[BC30390]
> 'AspNetCore.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.DataRegionExprHost(Of
> TMemberType, TCellType).m_memberTreeHostsRemotable' is not accessible
> in this context because it is 'Friend'.’

Interestingly, when I refrain from using the Column Visibility Expression, everything functions correctly. This issue has been documented and remains unresolved as of now, as indicated **[here](https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/23)**.

I am curious if there are any alternative options or stable third-party RDLC reporting libraries available for .NET Core 5 or subsequent versions to manage pdf, excel, and csv reports.